# Why does nvidia-detector return none?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10

Could you help me find out why nvidia-detector returns none? Here is the output of some troubleshooting commands, by the way, Nvidia settings is installed and the driver is installed via software and updated settings

`inxi -SGx`

```
System:    Host: habi-G551VW Kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.2.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.26.1 (Gtk 3.22.24-0ubuntu1) Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.5 ) drivers: modesetting,nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.90 Direct Render: Yes
```

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia`

```
ii  nvidia-384                                 384.90-0ubuntu3.17.10.1                     amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.90
ii  nvidia-384-dev                             384.90-0ubuntu3.17.10.1                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-cuda-dev                            8.0.61-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development files
ii  nvidia-cuda-doc                            8.0.61-1                                    all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL documentation
ii  nvidia-cuda-gdb                            8.0.61-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Debugger (GDB)
ii  nvidia-cuda-toolkit                        8.0.61-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development toolkit
ii  nvidia-modprobe                            384.81-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-dev:amd64                    8.0.61-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL development files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-384                      384.90-0ubuntu3.17.10.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.5                                       amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-profiler                            8.0.61-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
ii  nvidia-settings                            384.81-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-visual-profiler                     8.0.61-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA Visual Profiler for CUDA and OpenCL
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you using this PPA? https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 2):

By going to the  [Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us), you can pick your card and see what driver version you need. I did this, had a problem with one set of drivers in the repository, found that if I went to an older version then ran apt updates, it took me to the newer version but this time it worked.

I guess the newer one had a bad file that the older one provided?

That might help, sorry can't help more.